# Lost Messages history for Legacy Contact

Tags: messages, bug, apple-id

After designating one of my contacts as a Legacy Contact all of my history for that contact in Messages has vanished (along with all links on other apps to shared content in Messages). The contact has the history on all their devices, but it is absent from all of mine.

Where did the history go? Why does designating a Legacy Contact delete it?

More importantly: How do I get it back?

Apple's solution is to do a complete restore from backup on all devices. That's not an option for me.

I have a recent iMazing backup of my iPhone, so I can actually see and review the full Messages history there for each individual contact including all the missing Messages from my Legacy Contact. But there is no way to restore just that contact from iMazing nor is there a way (despite IMazing's promotion of it's unique ability to "select which content is restored") to restore just Messages from a backup either.

I also have a disk image of my Mac so I have a recent backed up copy of `~/Library/Messages`. And this seems the preferred animist promising approach from what I can glean from reading other answers. However most of this are old and often describe folders that no longer exist in Big Sur. Can I just copy `~/Library/Messages` to my Mac to restore all of my Message history. If so, what are the detailed steps, specifically with respect to enabling Messages storage in iCloud (which is what I currently do and where I want to end up) and ensuring the restore propagates to all my devices?

Comment: Favorite quote from exchange about this with apple support when I asked how setting someone as a Legacy Contact could have triggered the loss of my Messages history with them: "It's made by humans and things made by humans can break".